# $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the solutiton of $\frac{2\cdot \sin(x) \cdot \cos(2x)}{\cos (x) \cdot \sin (2x)} - 5 \tan(x) + 5 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$x_1$ and $x_2$ are the solutiton of $\frac{2\cdot \sin(x) \cdot \cos(2x)}{\cos (x) \cdot \sin (2x)} - 5 \tan(x) + 5 = 0$

then, $\tan(x_1 + x_2) = ....$

i can do it by doing it
$\dfrac{2\cdot \sin(x) \cdot (\cos^2x - \sin^2x)}{\cos (x) \cdot 2 \sin x \cos x} - 5 \tan(x) + 5 = 0$

leads to $(\sin x - \cos x)(\sin x + 6 \cos x) = 0$

but it's complicated, do you know the less complicated way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is $ \frac{2\tan x}{\tan 2x} - 5 \tan x + 5 = 0$, as one sees from rearranging the first term. The double angle formula for $\tan$ gives $\frac{2 \tan x }{\tan 2x} = 1 - \tan^2 x$ and therefore $(1 - \tan^2 x) - 5 \tan x + 5 = 0$, which simplifies to $\tan^2 x + 5 \tan x - 6 = 0$. This finally gives $\tan x = -6$ or $\tan x = +1$.

Finally, using the addition formula, we get $\tan(x_1 + x_2) = \frac{-6 + 1}{1 - (-6)\cdot(+1)} = \frac{-5}{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $t=\tan(x)$ to make
$$2t \frac{1-t^2}{2t}-5t+5=0\implies t^2+5t-6=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Convert all to $\tan$:
$$\frac{2 \sin(x) \cos(2x)}{\cos(x) \sin(2x)} - 5 \tan(x) +5 = \frac{2 \tan(x)}{\tan(2x)} - 5 \tan(x) +5 = (1 - \tan^2(x)) - 5 \tan(x) + 5$$
$$ \Longrightarrow \tan^2(x) + 5 \tan(x) - 6 = 0$$
Now we have:
$$\tan(x_1 + x_2) = \frac{\tan(x_1) + \tan(x_2)}{1 - \tan(x_1)\tan(x_2)} = \frac{-b/a}{1-c/a} = \frac{-5/1}{1-(-6/1)} = \frac{-5}{1+6} = -\frac{5}{7}$$
Without need to compute the roots!